# implicit ContourPlot - variable upper bound

Tags: plotting

I want to plot an actually simple implicit function in 2D

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, x}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

should yield one arc with radius $1$ in the range from $0$ to $\pi/4$ (measured counterclockwise beginning on the x-axis).

Problem seems to be the variable upper y-bound.
Mathematica aks for a 'machine-sized real number'
Is there an easy way to resolve this problem?

TIA

Comment: Why do you want to put `x` there in the first place?

Comment: Better solutions are warmly welcome ;)

Comment: Sorry, misread your question slightly - what version of Mathematica are you using? This syntax seems to be supported in 11.3, but not 11.2. You can use the `{x,y}∈ImplicitRegion[…]` syntax in older versions

Comment: Or `, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y < x]`